# Do current MVPs need recommendations?

Tags: mvp

Do current MVPs need recommendations from Sitecore MVPs or Sitecore Employees?

How this process works for current MVPs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I know current MVPs doesn't need recommendation this year.

Existing MVPs will receive an email automatically inviting them to create an acount, they do not need to be nominated by another MVP or Sitecore employee.

They need just to login on https://mvp.sitecore.com/application and they need to apply for Sitecore MVP 2019.

Comment: As a note on this, the email used was the email address provided by the MVP for their 2018 application. Make sure to check whatever email you provided last year!

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, at least 1 recommendation is needed for those who are not 2018 MVPs.

For 2018 MVPs recommendations can help if there are some doubts about the candidate, but they are not required.

Comment: I don't think it matters. If you're a 2018 MVP you are responsible for "keeping it up". If you feel you're in a grey zone where recommendations are needed, it's more like "too little, too late".

Comment: I think it does matter. E.g. if you're one of the local SUG organizers and there is not much about you online, but you receive 5 recommendations saying that you're crucial part of the SUG team, they may help. It can be different for every single candidate.